# How can I get a value in a nested dictionary with lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```py
{'kind': 'identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse',
 'users': [{'createdAt': '1592641942167',
            'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
            'emailVerified': False,
            'lastLoginAt': '1592819446718',
            'lastRefreshAt': '2020-06-22T09:50:46.718Z',
            'localId': 'xHfdxJ2ALpQwscsoN2Pvf2GTH8E3',
            'passwordHash': 'UkVEQUNURUQ=',
            'passwordUpdatedAt': 1592641942167,
            'providerUserInfo': [{'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
                                  'federatedId': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
                                  'providerId': 'password',
                                  'rawId': 'amer.99@gmail.com'}],
            'validSince': '1592641942'}]}
```

I want to print the value for the `'emailVerified'` key, so what do I have to do?

Comment: `dictionary['users'][0].get('emailVerified')`

Comment: In what way? Just a long list of `True` or `False`, or associated with some other attribute of the same dict?

Answer (score 2):

Using `pprint`

```py
from pprint import pprint

pprint({'kind': 'identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse', 'users': [{'localId': 
'xHfdxJ2ALpQwscsoN2Pvf2GTH8E3', 'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com', 'passwordHash': 'UkVEQUNURUQ=', 
'emailVerified': False, 'passwordUpdatedAt': 1592641942167, 'providerUserInfo': [{'providerId': 
'password', 'federatedId': 
'amer.99@gmail.com', 'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com', 'rawId': 'amer.99@gmail.com'}], 
'validSince': '1592641942', 'lastLoginAt': '1592819446718', 'createdAt': '1592641942167', 
'lastRefreshAt': '2020-06-22T09:50:46.718Z'}]})
```

-> Output:

```
{'kind': 'identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse',
 'users': [{'createdAt': '1592641942167',
            'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
            'emailVerified': False,
            'lastLoginAt': '1592819446718',
            'lastRefreshAt': '2020-06-22T09:50:46.718Z',
            'localId': 'xHfdxJ2ALpQwscsoN2Pvf2GTH8E3',
            'passwordHash': 'UkVEQUNURUQ=',
            'passwordUpdatedAt': 1592641942167,
            'providerUserInfo': [{'email': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
                                  'federatedId': 'amer.99@gmail.com',
                                  'providerId': 'password',
                                  'rawId': 'amer.99@gmail.com'}],
            'validSince': '1592641942'}]}
```

Here we can neatly see the structure:
and the way to access the
`emailVerified` is `my_dict['users'][0]['emailVerified']`
(where my_dict is just the name of the dict object)

Comment: Obviously, it's not all that clear to see how to access the value from the structure.

Comment: @tobias_k - please elaborate why this doesn't help?

Comment: this should do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is named 'sampleDict', you can read it like this

```
sampleDict['users'][0].get('emailVerified', False)
```

0 is the index of the list of users

'get' method takes two parameters

param1 is the key you wish to retrieve, param2 is the default value you wish to return if the key is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to that value using `dictionary["users"][0]["emailVerified"]`